# Python - List comprehension with tuple unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples like:
    `tuple_list = [ (0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8) ]`

I need to create a list where each tuple is converted into a list with other static items added e.g.:

```
new_list = [ [var1, var2, unpack(t)] for t in tuple_list ]
```

How would I accomplish this in python?

Comment: Why downvote, question is legit?

Comment: Question is tagged py27 but in py35+ there's new unpacking in literals: `[[var1, var2, *t] for t in tuple_list]`

Answer (score 6):

If your tuple is not too long, you can do:

```
[var1, var2, k, v, r for (k, v, r) in youList]
```

otherwise, write a function:

```
def myPack(*arg):
    return list(arg)
[myPack(var1, var2, *I) for I in youList]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_list = [ [var1, var2] + list(t) for t in tuple_list ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [ [var1, var2] + [val for val in t] for t in tuple_list]
// => [[var1, var2, 0, 1, 2], [var1, var2, 3, 4, 5], [var1, var2, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: thanks you pointed me in the right direction, it can be made more succinct by replacing the nested list comprehension with a simple `list(t)`